# File input loop in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, for-loop

I want to automate a task on ArcGIS, and I have created a function chain working well. The chain simply evaluates a point, calculates multiple hydrological rasters & values and gives output. I have 300+ points and I have to evaluate and save each one's layers results separately so I need a for loop in the start that counts the file & loops and outputs. Below you can find a Matlab - R-esque imaginary code flow what I need to do.

What I need as a code :

```
%% assume points.shp with 300 entities

N = count_entities(points.shp) %% Get N = 300

For i = 1:N

Point(i) = extract(points.shp(i))

Output(i) = model_function(Point(i))

End
```

I am aware of naming problems - I can solve with variable name nodes so no problem with that, my main lack-point of knowledge is establishing primary count and loop steps.

Can someone offer some step by step guidance creating this nodes?

Comment: You tag and talk about ModelBuilder, but mention writing Python code. Please confirm you are talking ONLY about ModelBuilder? Are you using ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: By "points" you mean point layer? You have 300 point layers, or one point layer with 300 features in it?

Comment: For KHibma's question, I prefer it ONLY about ModelBuilder since I don't know Python, but if I can only do this in Python, I would try to force it. I understand coding scheme of Python when I take a glance, I just didnt use it & learn it in the past. And I am using Arcmap. For BERA's question, I have a single point file with 300 entities.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Iterate Feature Selection](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_DBDEB1775AAE42F683B46752BB2CC0EF) iterator:

> Iterates over features in a feature class

So for each point the model is executed once and outputs a file.